# Any way to schedule a passive profile-change? (connectivity, volume etc.)

Tags: applications, notifications, push-notifications, automation

What I am wondering is if there is any way to make Android change its profiles **passively** from one state to the other at e.g. 3 pm in the afternoon local time:

- Through Android internally (with some tweaks)
- Through an Android app
- Through a 3rd party mod (Cyanogen etc.)
- Through ...?

**Whereas the state change should be:**

- From "Airplane mode" (set) to Wifi/3G
- From "Mute"/vibration (set) to maximum volume, i.e. visible sound
- Optionally: From E-Mail/Notifications on-demand (Pull) to "Push", i.e. the moment I get out of airplane mode and mute/vibrate mode, I want to get the push alerts of the last hours.

I wonder if 3. is possible, I never changed much concerning my notification settings.

Any Android version welcome, currently I run 4.0, but plan to upgrade to CM10.

What I don't want (and don't have) is NCF, because it involves me being active.
The whole reason for having a scheduled, predefined activity is that I can "set and forget" it and can focus on my work being assured that I will keep my deadline or whatever. I don't want to be actively involved.

Comment: Use llama or tasker app.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Profile Scheduler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wetpalm.ProfileScheduler) app.

With Profile Scheduler, you can define many 'profiles' (a set of settings covering Wifi On/Off, Data-Sync On/Off, Volume settings, Display Brightness, Bluetooth state, and many others -- for full set of settings, please refer to the Play Store page I linked above).

After creating your desired profiles (e.g., Sleep, Work, Outdoors, Driving, etc.), in the next tab (of the app) you can create 'rules' that will trigger a profile to automatically be activated. The 'rules' can be as simple as a 'time-of-day schedule' rule, or something more complex like geo-location based rules, wifi SSID-based rules, etc.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit?

Comment: Have you checked the linked app? With Profile Scheduler, you first create a set of profiles (Wifi on/off, volume, auto datasync, etc.). Then, you use its "Scheduler" facility to set which profile to trigger at a certain time of day (or combination of time & day, or any other state the app can detect).

Comment: Answers should stand on their own. It'd be great if you added that information to the answer.

Comment: Hmm... I *really* don't want to repeat information that can easily be read in the Play store... but I'll edit my answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There's a (relatively) new app out called [Silence](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.epsilonlabs.silence.ads). There is also an [ad-free paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.epsilonlabs.silence).

> Silence allows you to toggle your ringer, Wi-fi, Bluetooth, and airplane mode settings automatically over scheduled intervals.
>
> Features:
>
> - Simple, intuitive Holo-themed interface
> - Schedule events that occur once, or repeat on certain days of the week
> - Change your ringer to silent, vibrate, or normal mode
> - Turn Wi-fi, Bluetooth, and airplane mode on and off
> - Change your settings back automatically when the scheduled event ends

[Lifehacker had a review](http://lifehacker.com/5967423/silence-for-android-adjusts-your-sound-and-wireless-settings-automatically).

Answer (score 0):

The [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) app will allow you to do this, although this app can be daunting for a new user.

Tasker allows you to automate task on you Android device - the things you would like should be easily possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another good app for changing the volume is [Audio Mode Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moleapps.audiomodeswitcher) There you can do everything according to automatically switching the audio-profile in one App.
You can define a weekly schedules to switch to a given profile. You can schedule multiple start and end times (i.e. when you go to sleep etc.).
It also offers a calendar integration, where you can choose to switch to a certain mode at a defined event. These events can be chosen according to their calendar and/or keyword based - I think this is very useful i.e. I can mute the phone if the word "cinema" is in the title and mute at all events in my work-calendar.
Furthermore location-based switching is also possible.