# How can I get my Galaxy S3 to behave at night? (turn off LED and notifications, etc.)

Tags: settings, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to schedule a passive profile-change? (connectivity, volume etc.)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/any-way-to-schedule-a-passive-profile-change-connectivity-volume-etc)

I've got a Galaxy S3, and I love it, but it drives me crazy at night sometimes. GMail will get a new message and it'll ring. The LED sometimes flashes all night long, etc. I've seen a couple of apps that purport to solve these problems, but they've got some bad reviews. Can anyone recommend a good way to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People might expect me to recomment [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) including a profile -- so I will do this first. But I will include another, free solution as well this time.

First, how to solve this with Tasker? Quite easy:

**Condition:** Time (10pm to 7 am, for example)
**Task:**

- *Airplane On* (optionally, so no incoming calls)
- *WiFi On* (so weather-updates and streaming music for my alarm clock still make it)
- *Silent Mode On* (that's the important one: everything off except for media volume)

This is just an example of what can be done. Many more options are available, but Tasker costs you about 5 Euro (it's really worth it, as other answers here tell you as well -- you can let hell freeze with it!). If that's too much for you, you have two options: First check with the free 7 day trial from the [Tasker homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) -- or look for an alternative. Well, to be honest: nothing can get near *Tasker*, but for your case there are some options left:

- [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic) is a very good scheduler (can deal well with time based events, like the above described)
- [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) can do with location based, time based (don't be fooled by the name of the app), and more
- I know I repeat myself: *Tasker* can do all this and much, much more. And if you feel there's something missing: there are so many addons available (all *Locale* addons fit). And so many apps interface with it...

Comment: I'm checking out the free trial of Tasker now. I suspect this will be the solution I go with. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could be at service :)

Comment: I'll be using Tasker to take care of most of what I want to do. Unfortunately, it looks like setting the LED status is the one thing it's not very good at. I've just disabled the LED for notifications and for charging (which I usually do at night).

Answer (score 2):

A GS3 running Jellybean has this built-in in the form of "blocking mode".

In the settings, there's a menu called "blocking mode".  You can set it to disable notifications and the LED indicator and specify between what times you want it like that.

Also lets you block incoming calls except for numbers you specifically allow and disable the alarm/timer.

[GSMarena's review of the update](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_iii_jelly_bean-review-823p4.php) mentions it.  It's at the bottom of the 4th page including screenshots of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Two Options I can think of:

1. Root and install CM10 (you won't miss touchwiz)

   Using this method, you could use the built in *Quiet Hours* setting under

   Menu > Settings > Sound > Quiet Hours
2. Use an app like Tasker / Locale

   These are really cool apps, they give you a load of control based on lots of conditions.  Of course, other people suggested other options similar to this.

Comment: Stock has no such option, alas.

Comment: Stock Jellybean has the "blocking mode", which is like quiet hours (disable notifications and LED), but also lets you block unwanted callers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Go power master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.gopowermaster&hl=en) for this purpose and then configure the time to change the mode at specific time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).  It's got a steep learning curve, but it's worth it.

I use it just for two or three very simple things, and your use case is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, gotta love Android for this! Another paid app I would like to tell you about is [Juice Defender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5sYXRlZHJvaWQuanVpY2VkZWZlbmRlciJd). There is a night mode which you can use. As an added benefit, it also saves you battery, by turning on data in frequencies that you can set. The free version can only choose between 15m and 30m. With the paid version can also set location specific power settings.

If you just want to turn it off during the night, you can just set the phone to Airplane Mode during the night.

But you might forget to unset it in the morning. Another app, which is primarily a funky power widget, also has a night mode. Its called [Battery Widget? Reborn!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.reborn.beta&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC5odWJhbGVrLmFuZHJvaWQucmVib3JuLmJldGEiXQ..) Yeah, the  exclamations are part of the name.

Tasker and others might be a tad overkill for what you are looking for, but yeah, once you realize the possibilities, you wont use anything else.

Welcome to the symbiotic Android ecosystem :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can take the battery out and put it back in when you need it. Or can you just power it off to save battery life. This'll work if you don't need it on at all during the night as in you don't have an alarm/important notifications.

Comment: Why pull out the battery vs turn off? I'm a little confused by that?

Comment: Probably too hasty of a response on my part. I guess it would be a worse case scenario if other options didn't work.

Comment: Airplane Mode :)

Comment: @theTuxRacer Airplane Mode only turns the radios off, it doesn't stop notifications. Many apps have scheduled notifications of many kinds that don't need to communicate with a server continuously, for example think of things like Calendar reminders.

Comment: Silent Mode would do (turns off all sound except for media and alarms -- so no more ringing and no notification sounds). But one easily forgets to turn it on in the evening -- or to turn it off in the morning, so it'd better be used together with some automation tool. Ah, no way to use some automation to take the battery out/in I'm afraid :)